# Catch without try error

Tags: java, netbeans

I would like to get sum results from two textfields. I wanted a way to return nill in the result textbox. Why is the following code throwing "cath without try" error. Where am I wrong.Please assist.

```
private void AddButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  try
   {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(FirstNumberTextField.getText());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(SecondNumberTextField.getText());
    ResultTextField1.setText((x + y)+"");
   {
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       ResultTextField1.setText("");
   }       
}
```

Comment: netbeans didn't help to find that error?? strange, very strange...

Comment: Probably did, but this would be the first error it ran into. Last one would have been missing }, any number of them in between.

Answer (score 6):

You have one opening brace too many:

```
private void AddButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  try
   {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(FirstNumberTextField.getText());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(SecondNumberTextField.getText());
    ResultTextField1.setText((x + y)+"");
   } // <-- This one was wrong.
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       ResultTextField1.setText("");
   }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `{` instead of a `}` at the end of the `try` block. This puts the `catch` block inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an open brace at the end of your try block instead of a closing brace.

```
   {
   catch(Exception e)
```

should be

```
   }
   catch(Exception e)
```

Answer (score 0):

The brace *before* the catch block must be closing brace `}`, but you've written another open brace `{`. In fact all blocks (if, else, try, catch, finally, while, for, etc.) always come in balanced sequences of `{}`